# Poetry script: No file/folder found

Tags: fastapi, python-poetry

I am currently building a backend using FastAPI and I am facing some issues to run the backend using poetry scripts. This is my project structure:

```
├── backend
  └── src
  └── asgi.py
  └── Dockerfile
  └── poetry.lock
  └── pyproject.toml
```

**pyproject.toml**

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "backend"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Pierre-Alexandre35 <46579114+pamousset75@users.noreply.github.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
uvicorn = "^0.17.6"
fastapi = "^0.78.0"
psycopg2 = "^2.9.3"
jwt = "^1.3.1"
python-multipart = "^0.0.5"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
foo='asgi:__main__'
```

If I am running  `poetry run python asgi.py`, it is working perfectly but if I am using `poetry foo` script, I am getting `No file/folder found for package backend`. Those are all combinaisons I tried and I have the same error for every `poetry run foo`:

```
foo='asgi:main'
foo='backend.asgi:__main__'
foo='backend.asgi:main'
foo='backend.asgi:.'
```

Comment: Did you run `poetry install`? What is the content of `asgi.py` (the relevant bits)?

Answer (score 5):

Your project structure does not seem to be correct. Assuming `backend` is the package u are trying to create.

Use this structure

```
└── pyproject.toml
└── poetry.lock
└── README.md
├── backend
  └── src
  └── asgi.py
  └── Dockerfile
  └── __init__.py
```

Also in scripts use. (Assuming you are trying to run **main** with `foo`)

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
foo='backend.asgi:__main__'
```